# Distinct/Unique values in a property

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way to extract the unique values in a property assuming there is some separator character. So if I have

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Values>foo;bar;bar;foo</Values>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there a way of getting a property whose value is "foo;bar" without the repeated values? I am aware of the Item function Distinct but haven't been able to work out a way of using it for properties.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how you can use the ItemGroup's Distinct method and assign the result back to the property:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="TestDistinct" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Values>foo;bar;bar;foo</Values>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="TestDistinct">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ValueGroup Include="$(Values)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DistinctValues>@(ValueGroup->Distinct())</DistinctValues>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="$(DistinctValues)" />
   </Target>
 </Project>
```

Quick explanation how it works. The MSBuild's PropertyGroup can only hold single-valued elements (properties). ItemGroup is an analog of a list. Since you need to make operations on list of values -- to extract distinct list, you need an ItemGroup. Then you apply `Distinct()` method and assign result to a new property, called here `<DistinctValues>`. Now you have a property that contains distinct elements from original `<Values>` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works great. Would be nice if there was something like $(Values->Distinct(';') operating on a Property